# What is the best way to subscribe an SQS queue in CN region to an SNS topic in NA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

SNS topics in NA region can't simply broadcast messages to an SQS queue in CN.

One possible solution would be:

SNS in NA publishes to SQS in NA -> Service in NA get the message in NA -> Service in NA publish the message again in SNS in CN -> SNS in CN republishes to SQS in CN -> Service in CN processes the message

In this solution, we implement a broadcaster that transfers messages from NA to CN. Are there any better ways than this?

Comment: I assume this is a limitation in the CN region?  Other regions do allow this.

Comment: Yes, all other regions can transfer data between each other except for CN.